# "DI CUI LAMENTARSI": comparativa o causale? (Analisi del periodo)

Tags: grammatical-analysis

*Ci rispose che ci sarebbero state cose più serie DI CUI LAMENTARSI.*

Mi viene un gran dubbio su come vada interpretata la frase "di cui lamentarsi". Si tratta di una subordinata comparativa oppure di una causale? 
-Direi comparativa perchè viene espresso un confronto: ci sono cose più serie di altre. 
-Direi invece anche causale perchè in realtà potrei cambiare la frase in "a causa delle quali lamentarsi" e il significato non cambia. 
Come faccio a distinguere e sapere quale è giusta?

Comment: Che c'entra la comparativa? Non costituisce il secondo termine di paragone, come sarebbe invece “...cose più serie di quanto sembrassero ieri”. Qui il secondo termine di paragone è implicito: per esempio “...cose più serie [di quelle che abbiamo detto] di cui lamentarsi”. È sicuramente una proposizione relativa (implicita); non so poi se il testo a cui fai riferimento introduca ulteriori tipi di relative.

Comment: Avevo pensato a una comparativa perchè nella principale leggo "cose più serie". Però è vero manca poi il termine di paragone vero e proprio.

Comment: @DaG: Potresti scrivere il tuo commento come risposta?

Comment: Penso anche io che sia una proposizione relativa ("cui" rel. al nome precedente).

Comment: Noi ci lamentiamo di A; lui risponde che B è più serio di A e che semmai ci dovremmo lamentare di B. A e B sono cose di cui lamentarsi.

Comment: @DaG So che la domanda è vecchia, ma se non rispondi un un paio d'ore rispondo io (sto cercando di ripulire un po' il sito e di assicurarmi che ci siano meno domande possibili senza risposta)

Comment: Fai pure, @DenisNardin: non sono particolarmente ferrato sull'analisi logica e del periodo, e già altrove ho espresso l'opinione che in parte sia fatta di distinzioni bizantine. E grazie per il lavorone per rispondere alle domande o chiuderle!

Answer (score 4):

Non si tratta di né di una proposizione comparativa, né di una causale. Come ha osservato DaG nei commenti, è una proposizione relativa. Questo si può osservare grazie alla presenza del pronome relativo *cui*. Vediamo cosa dice la [*Grammatica Italiana Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-relative_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):

> Nell’analisi del periodo, le *proposizioni relative* sono proposizioni subordinate introdotte da un pronome o da un avverbio relativo che esprimono una qualità riferita a un elemento (detto *antecedente*) contenuto nella proposizione.
>
> [...]
>
> [L]e *proposizioni relative implicite* sono introdotte da pronomi relativi con funzione di complemento indiretto, come cui, a cui, di cui, con cui ecc., oppure dalle preposizioni da, a e con. Hanno sempre il verbo all’infinito.

In questo caso, *di cui lamentarsi* è una proposizione relativa implicita, con antecedente *cose*. Essa ha lo scopo di esplicare meglio a quali *cose* l'autore faccia riferimento.